# Msxml2.serverxmlhttp.6.0 in classic ASP sends GET instead of POST

Tags: post, vbscript, get, asp-classic, serverxmlhttp

I'm trying to send a request to Twilio SMS Gateway from an .asp page of the product we're supporting.

I am using the following code to compose a request and send it:

```
Set oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0")
sMethod = "POST"
oXMLHTTP.Open sMethod, sUrl, false, smsAuthUser, smsAuthPass 'url, username and password are valid and included in configuration file
oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic "& base64(smsAuthUser&"."&smsAuthPass)
oXMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(sPostData)
oXMLHTTP.Send sPostData
```

The request is being sent, but instead of sending a message it retrieves a list of messages sent earlier (GET request behavior).

Same request with the same authorization and post data from Chrome Postman works like a charm, so it appears to be the xmlhttp object issue.

What can cause the object to send a request using wrong method, and what are potential workarounds?

Comment: You need to run fiddler or something and check what is being sent, at the moment you are making an assumption about the cause. First, prove your theory then ask a question. Just saying it works from Postman so it must be xmlHttp's fault is not conclusive enough.

Comment: If that is the exact code you use to send the request I cannot see how you can be sending a `GET` request, like I said above only running [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) will confirm either way what is actually happening. It's a great tool and should be must for any server based xhr work.

Comment: After debug with php..it seem `Msxml2.serverXMLHTTP.6.0` always use `GET` method, no data sent with `send`..unable to add `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` to header.. I heard this happen in window 7 but not in window 10..